# How to increase a variable"s value by 1 eveytime I fire a function

Tags: javascript

How do I do it 
I have
 pos=0 and each time I fire a function 
Pos+=10 and how to store how many times I fire it in another var

Comment: use some global variable to store count..

Comment: `var counter = 0` followed by `counter += 1;`

Comment: This is a really basic question - maybe consider solving it by yourself to improve your JS skills. 
If you don't wan't that share your code and possibly someone will do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do the following:
var count = pos/10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
let pos = 0
function count (){
  pos = pos + 10;
  console.log('fired count-' , pos/10 , ', value- ', pos )
}

for(var i= 0 ;i<5 ; i++){
  count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count;
if (count == undefined || count == "" || count == 0) 
{
  var count = 0;
}
function add()
{
   count+=10;
  alert(count);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add();">click</button>
```